# How to get SSID using android Java for API 28 and 29?

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

In my case, I am trying to get SSID by using android java for API 28 and API 29. Here, I am using below code but it is returning . How to resolve it?

**Get SSID Code Below**

```
public String getWifiName() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext ().getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();
    String ssid  = info.getSSID();
    return ssid;
}
```

Comment: Do you have all necessary permissions, including ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION?

Comment: @GabeSechan I gave that permission even it is returning same. can you please post some code. Please help mean this